# NSMutableArray has 6 (some example) items. 3 IDs and 3 arrays (info about those 3 IDs). How to remove those numbers (IDs)

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray, xcode8

```
(
    65,
    61,
    82,

        {
        FOMobilePhone = "";
        FOName = "XXX";
        FOTitle = "PRODUCTION DIRECTOR";
        FOWorkEMail = "AAA@example.com";
        FOWorkPhone = "+12345";
        Id = 65;
    },
        {
        FOMobilePhone = "";
        FOName = "BBB";
        FOTitle = "GSC EGYPT OPERATION LEAD";
        FOWorkEMail = "BBB@example.com";
        FOWorkPhone = "+12345";
        Id = 61;
    },
        {
        FOMobilePhone = "";
        FOName = "CCC";
        FOTitle = "PRODUCTION, DIRECTOR";
        FOWorkEMail = "CCC@example.com";
        FOWorkPhone = "+12345";
        Id = 82;
    }
}
```

First 3 items are IDs and remaining 3 arrays are their respective data. NSMutableArray has 6 (some example) items. 3 IDs and 3 arrays (info about those 3 IDs). How to remove those numbers (IDs)?

Comment: always first three items are IDs or it can be 4 or 5 or something else?

Comment: if i get 10 items, first 5 are IDs, then remaining 5 are the data related to that ID. As I shown above I got 6 items in my MutableArray, first 3 are IDs and remaining 3 are its data. So always first 'n' numbers are IDs and remaining 'n' numbers are its data. So totally I always get '2n' data in my MutableArray

Comment: check my answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

Let `someArray`  = `NSMUtableArray` you are getting from server.

```
NSMutableIndexSet *discardedItems = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
NSUInteger index = 0;
for (id someObject in someArray) {
    if ([someObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
        [discardedItems addIndex:index];
    } 
    index++;
}
[someArray removeObjectsAtIndexes:discardedItems];
```

Finally , someArray will have only the data without IDs.

Comment: Thank u soooooooooooooo much!!! Worked perfectly!!!!! Thanks a ton/alot... U made my day!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

if NSMutableArray name is arr1 then you can do like this to remove three ID:

[arr1 removeObject:0];

[arr1 removeObject:1];

[arr1 removeObject:2];

Comment: It is not constant, I get it from web service

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what language you're using. If it's Swift, you could write a filter command that would get rid of the Int items.

If it's Objective-C you don't have that option, but you could do it various other ways. I'd suggest using `filterUsingPredicate` (if it's a mutable array) or `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` if it's an immutable array.